# How to place the scrollbar of a JScrollPane in a custom position?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jtextarea

So I have a JTextArea and right next to it I have placed a JLabel with the same height.
I want to make the JTextArea scrollable but when I do so, the scrollbar goes between the JTextArea and the JLabel. This is the default but I want to place the scrollbar on the right of the JLabel so that it scrolls the JTextArea but does nothing to the JLabel. The JLabel contains small image, nothing else and I want that image to be between the JTextArea and it's scrollbar. What is a good way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) add your textArea to a scrollPane set with verticalScrollbar.NEVER
and horizontalScrollbar.NEVER (textArea would need to have wordWrap set)

2) add the scrollPane to a JPanel(borderLayout) at BorderLayout.WEST

3) add your label to the panel at BorderLayout.CENTER

4) add a JScrollBar to the panel at BorderLayout.EAST

5) get the verticalScrollbar of the scrollPane and set its model to that of the
scrollBar at BorderLayout.EAST

if the frame is resizable, and you want the textArea/scrollpane to take the 
additional/less space, (2) and (3) (or (3) and (4)) would need to be combined into a separate panel so that the textArea/scrollPane is in the CENTER area of a panel

Answer (score 0):

Make a JPanel, and put the textarea and the image in it, and lay it out horizontally. then set the panel as a JScrollPane's viewport view.

Comment: I kind of made it work with a BoxLayout but then the JLabel moves as well(when the JTextPane becomes "scrollable") and the scroll bar goes over the JLabel because it's from the inside of the panel.